# Republishing Questions and Answers on another website

Tags: discussion

I noticed that a question I asked on this site has been republished on [another site](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/917697/gwidgets-gfile-directing-user-to-a-folder-in-the-browser-pop-up-ask-question.html).

I'm not sure if that's a particular concern for anyone but thought someone might want to know.

Comment: They seen to only clone questions. For example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538311/weird-glitches-on-android-4-4api-level-18-after-using-egl-context-v2-0) and [this](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/909954/weird-glitches-on-android-44api-level-18-after-using-egl-context-v20-ask-question.html) is the same question, but with different answers.